# Fixed Nav Menu With jQuery

Tags: jquery

It has a navigation menu and a search entry. As you go down, the search input disappears and a search text appears in the nav menu. But I ran into a problem, it doesn't go down dynamically as I go down, how can I prevent this?

```js
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
  var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (currentScroll > 100) {
    jQuery('.header').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0'});
    jQuery('.s-icon').css('display','block');
    jQuery('.sInput').css({display: 'none'});
    jQuery('.s-icon').click(function(){
        jQuery('.sInput').css({position: 'fixed', top:'50px',display:'block'});
    });
  } else {
    jQuery('.header').css({position: 'relative'});
    jQuery('.s-icon').css('display','none');
    jQuery('.sInput').css({position: 'relative',display:'block',top:'0px'});
  }
});
```

```css
body{
  height:1500px;
  
}
ul{
  display:flex;
  
}
li{
    margin-right:2%;
    list-style:none;
}
.header{
  background:#CCC;
  width:100% !important;
}
.s-icon{
  display:none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.lorem{
  width:30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
  <li>About Us</li>
  <span class="s-icon">Search</span>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
<input class="sInput" type="search" placeholder="Search..">
</div>


<div class="lorem">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, eveniet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum vitae dolores cumque ducimus debitis nihil itaque dolor cupiditate quis ipsum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas numquam praesentium vitae repellat qui, libero veritatis soluta doloribus rerum harum, voluptate ab et, omnis eius dicta amet dignissimos commodi. Error eligendi deserunt, minus rem eius ut quisquam aperiam, suscipit odio! Consequatur dolores nam assumenda adipisci ipsa nemo laboriosam, blanditiis, distinctio.
</div>
```

Thank you advance.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, now I see. Please take a look at this to see if this is what you expected. It works just by adding a "sticky" class to the header:

```js
var header = $('#header'),
   stickyHeight = header.offset().top;

jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
   var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            
  if (currentScroll > stickyHeight) {
   header.addClass("sticky");
  } else {
   header.removeClass("sticky");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height:1500px;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  display:flex;
}
li {
  margin-right:2%;
  list-style:none;
}
#header {
  background:#CCC;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 25px;
}
.lorem {
width:30%;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.sticky + .lorem {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="header">
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Contact</li>
<li>About Us</li>
</ul>
<span class="s-icon">Search</span>
</div>

<div class="lorem">
<div>
<input class="sInput" type="search" placeholder="Search.." />
</div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, eveniet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum vitae dolores cumque ducimus debitis nihil itaque dolor cupiditate quis ipsum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas numquam praesentium vitae repellat qui, libero veritatis soluta doloribus rerum harum, voluptate ab et, omnis eius dicta amet dignissimos commodi. Error eligendi deserunt, minus rem eius ut quisquam aperiam, suscipit odio! Consequatur dolores nam assumenda adipisci ipsa nemo laboriosam, blanditiis, distinctio.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain my problem, I just want the nav menu to go down dynamically when I fix it. Don't suddenly jump down and go down step by step.